# How to selectively copy parts of my Time Machine backup onto my new OS (Yosemite)?

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, migration-assistant

I'm working with a 2013 iMac running with the newest Yosemite. There was something wrong on my system which required that I erase the internal HD and do a clean install. Fine. But when I use Migration Assistant to bring back the data it doesn't allow me to select, say, iTunes apart from all of my other "documents". That's a problem for two reasons:

1) It will take more than 24 hours to reinstall

2) It might add on whatever file corrupted my previous system.

I just got off the line with Apple Support and they had nothing apart from their manual, and my question was off manual.

What I would like to do is enter the existing copy of the TM backup so that I can selectively restore the files I know are not corrupt, like iTunes.

There must be some way to do this. I can't imagine Apple creating a backup plan where you'd put a corrupt OS back onto your system. Or it there another way, say through Terminal? My backup is 2TB and I'd prefer my computer not be out of commission for a full day while possibly corrupts files get loaded back into it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the migration assistant doesn't copy system files from your backup.  But you're right that *maybe* one of your home-folder's installed files (a PrefPane or something) could have caused your problem.

I would still run the full Migration Assistant (just let it run for however long it takes), and hope that the problem doesn't come back.  This is typically the case.

If you problem does come back, then you know it stems from your home folder, in which case you can boot while holding `Shift` down, to disable all non-essential extensions/plugins.  Then you can remove all 3rd party files from `/Users/HOME/Library/PreferencePanes, LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, QuickLook, Services` or whatever type of error you think was happening.